# How to install minishift in a customized directory in linux

Tags: linux, openshift, rhel, minishift

While trying to start minishift, it automatically updates the cache in the home directory.

```
/home/abc/.minishift/cache/.....
```

However I want minishift to use a custom directory instead of the default home directory as I am running out of space

Can this be achieved by changing any parameters during ./minishift start

Tried codeready containers too, but it copies in the default home directory..

```
FATA Failed to copy embedded 'crc_libvirt_4.5.1.crcbundle' from /opt/data/crc-linux-1.13.0-amd64/crc to /home/abc/.crc/cache/crc_libvirt_4.5.1.crcbundle: write /home/abc/.crc/cache/crc_libvirt_4.5.1.crcbundle: no space left on device
```

Comment: Caution: According to Minishift's Github repository: ```Minishift runs OpenShift 3.x clusters. Due to different installation methods, OpenShift 4.x clusters are not supported. To run OpenShift 4.x locally, use CodeReady Containers.``` In other words, with minishift you will run an older version of Openshift 3.11. If you want use a local Openshift >= 4, then you should go to CodeReady Containers.

Comment: tried code ready too .. but it copies in the default home directory..FATA Failed to copy embedded 'crc_libvirt_4.5.1.crcbundle' from /opt/data/crc-linux-1.13.0-amd64/crc to /home/abc/.crc/cache/crc_libvirt_4.5.1.crcbundle: write /home/abc/.crc/cache/crc_libvirt_4.5.1.crcbundle: no space left on device

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer to this :

```
 export MINISHIFT_HOME=/opt/softwares/
 echo 'export MINISHIFT_HOME=/opt/softwares/' >> ~/.bashrc
```

This helped in solving the redirecting the installation from home to customized directory.
Similar for crc installation  as well.

Answer (score 0):

As noted, you should use Code Ready Containers (CRC) and not minishift. This is a known issue and is being tracked here: [code-ready/crc/issues/817](https://github.com/code-ready/crc/issues/817).

The current workaround seems to be to create the directory where you want it to be and then create a symlink to `~/.crc`:

```
mkdir -p /opt/crc
ln -s /opt/crc/ ~/.crc
```